# How can I multiply numpy matrix elementwise without for loops?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization

I would like to apply the same matrix (3x3) to a large list of points that are contained in a vector.  The vector is of the form (40000 x 3).  The below code does the job but it is too slow.  Are there any numpy tricks I can use to eliminate the for loop and append function?

```
def apply_matrix_to_shape(Matrix,Points):
    """input a desired transformation and an array of points that are in 
    the format np.array([[x1,y1,z1],[x2,y2,z2],...,]]).   will output
    a new array of translated points with the same format"""
    New_shape = np.array([])
    M = Matrix
    for p in Points:
        New_shape = np.append(New_shape,[p[0]*M[0][0]+p[1]*M[0][1]+p[2]*M[0][2],
                                p[0]*M[1][0]+p[1]*M[1][1]+p[2]*M[1][2],
                                p[0]*M[2][0]+p[1]*M[2][1]+p[2]*M[2][2]])
    Rows = int(len(New_shape) / 3)
    return np.reshape(New_shape,(Rows,3))
```

Comment: whittle your problem down to a 3x3 and 20x3 example and show us your expected output

Comment: ex. Points = np.array([[x1,y1,z1],[x2,y2,z2]]) Matrix = np.array([1,0,0],[0,1,0], [0, 0, 1]]).  So M*Points = Points.  Just wish to apply matrix to each vector entry.

Comment: that doesn't really clear anything up. put a concrete example and expected output in the question itself (not as a comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want the [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) of both arrays (*not an element-wise one*). You just need to tranpose so the shapes are aligned, and transpose back the result:

```
m.dot(p.T).T
```

Or equivalently:

```
(m@p.T).T
```

---

```
m = np.random.random((3,3))
p = np.random.random((15,3))
np.allclose((m@p.T).T, apply_matrix_to_shape(m, p))
# True
```

Comment: I will have to study the allclose line but your second solution worked very well!  Thank you

Comment: They both do the same. All close checks that the results are the same, with some error margin, since we're working with floats @john

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, I think what you want is one of the main reason why NumPy came to live. You can use the dot product function and the transpose function (simply .T or .transpose())

```
import numpy as np

points = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
                   [4, 5, 6]])

T_matrix = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
                     [4, 5, 6],
                     [7, 8, 9]])


result = points.dot(T_matrix.T)

print(result)


>>>  [[ 14  32  50]
     [ 32  77 122]]
```